# DropDownList does not dispatch close event, when click outside

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, drop-down-menu, mouseevent, state

When I click on stage outside the opened DropDownList, somehow the close event does not dispatch. How can I force it to dispatch this event after clicking anywhere outside the DropDownList?

Or Let me ask my question through another way:

Imagine we have 2 states and when clicking outside the opened DropDownList, the state 1 will change to state 2. During this process how can be sure DropDownList closed completely and close event dispatched? And if not force it to close!

P.S 1: `DropDownList.closeDropDown(true);` does not force it to dispatch close event too!

P.S 2: Sorry didn't share any code, I have all of them in separated classes and was hard to share them here :D But I think in total the problem is understandable. I want force my DropDownList to dispatch close event whenever I'm clicking outside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the `stateChangeCompleteHandler` tried this:

```
DropDownList.dispatchEvent(new DropDownEvent(DropDownEvent.CLOSE));
```

*P.S: TanQ @Discipol for his point*

Answer (score 0):

do a manual dropdownlist.dispatchEvent( new Event( Event.Change ) ); :D

Comment: Tanq Discipol for your reply. I Actually did it. Even tried `dropdownlist.dispatchEvent(new Event(DropDownEvent.CLOSE));` but still no change :( I added more description to my post. It might help :)

Comment: Imagine I had an ex-wife and she hated me. Do what she did. Fake it :D create a new dropdown with the selected thing and destroy the old one.

Comment: Alternatively, make your own dropdown component that is less fickle. I usually rage on things like this. Did you know Video.clear() does not work? I manually cloned my Video instance and removed the otherone.